# Binary File Handling Program

Tags: c++, file

Please review this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float height[4]={17.5,8.4,2.9,7.9};
    ofstream file;
    file.open("BINARY.DAT", ios::binary | ios::out);
    file.write((char*)&height, sizeof(height));
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    height[i]=1;
    file.close();
    ifstream file1;
    file1.open("BINARY.DAT", ios::binary | ios::in);
    file1.read((char*)&height, sizeof(height));
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<height[i];
    }
    file1.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, alright. Sorry.

Comment: Alright, a moment.

Comment: @Incomputable But it gave me the output ?

Comment: What purpose does your code have? What problem does it solve? We need more context to effectively review this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using namespace std` is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). So you want to get rid of that.

Next, you should give you variables better names. `file` and `file1` are somewhat descriptiveness. Both tell you that it's a file, but neither says what kind of file.

Also check whether you were actually able to open the file. For example, the file could be write-only (and your `file.write(…)` works, but your `file1.read(…)` fails), read-only (and your `file.write(…)` fails, but your `file1.read(…)` works), or neither (and both fail).

What's that `4`, by the way? The number of elements in your `height` is a magic number. It might change at some point, and you have to update it throughout your program. That's error prone. It's somewhat fine for a small program like this, but in greater programs, you want to give that number a name (see above), something like `HEIGHT_LENGTH`. Same holds for `"BINARY.DAT"`. You don't want to accidentally use `"BINARY.Dar"` the second time.

Last but not least: use C-style cast as a last resort. You're looking for a `reinterpret_cast<char*>`.

By the way, if possible, keep the scope of your variables small:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    float height[4] = {17.5,8.4,2.9,7.9};

    // Write to the file:    
    {
        std::ofstream output;
        if(!output.open("BINARY.DAT", ios::binary | ios::out)){
            std::cerr << "could not open file!";
            return 1;
        }
        output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(height), sizeof(height));
        output.close(); // not actually necessary
    }

    // Set the value to 1 for testing purposes
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        height[i] = 1;
    }

    // Read back from the file:
    {
        std::ifstream input;
        if(!input.open("BINARY.DAT", ios::binary | ios::in)){
            std::cerr << "could not open file!";
            return 2;
        }
        input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(height), sizeof(height));
        input.close(); // not actually necessary
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << height[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've also added some whitespace. Keep in mind: you write code both for the machine *and* the human who's going to read that code later. That human might be you or your supervisor. Make sure that it's easy to read.